# Cache list of ids to check before querying database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, exception

I have a Asp.Net Mvc application that has a default route pattern of `/controller/action/id`.

This means the user could simply put any ID in the url if they are savy enough to figure it out. I could handle the exceptions, redirect the user to an error page (and I am) or any number of other solutions. There are only about 1200 possible valid IDs. I was considering caching a list of these IDs at the application level to check against before querying the database to save the expense of making a connection and handling the exceptions.

Does anyone have a good argument as to why this is a bad solution?

Comment: Dan, thank you for correcting my spelling and grammar. I'll try to do better in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you are prematurely optimizing an edge case.

Opening up a MSSQL db connection is cheap and returning nothing from `select * FROM primarykey` key is pretty inexpensive.